# Compiling SASS files in React component folders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass

I want to use sass stylesheets that are organized with each of my react components, like this:

```
  components/
  |- componentOne
     |- componentOne.js 
     |- componentOne.scss
  |- componentTwo
     |- componentTwo.js 
     |- componentTwo.scss
  |- componentThree
     |- componentThree.js 
     |- componentThree.scss
```

Are there any webpack settings / tools that will automatically load and compile all .scss files in a certain directory?

**EDIT:**

So the below is the current webpack config that I am using (written from a previous developer). I added in the line line in entries of `SRC_DIR + "/app/components/",` so that extract-text-webpack-plugin will pick up all of the .scss files in the components directory. But when I try to run the build I get the following error message. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
ERROR in multi babel-polyfill ./src/app/index.js ./src/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss ./src/app/components/ font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css rc-time-picker/assets/index.css react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css @trendmicro/react-toggle-switch/dist/react-toggle-switch.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/user123/dev/project/src/app/components/' in '/Users/user123/dev/project'
 @ multi babel-polyfill ./src/app/index.js ./src/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss ./src/app/components/ font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css rc-time-picker/assets/index.css react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css @trendmicro/react-toggle-switch/dist/react-toggle-switch.css
```

Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

const config = {
  entry: [
    "babel-polyfill",
    SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    SRC_DIR + "/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss",
    SRC_DIR + "/app/components/",
    "font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css",
    "rc-time-picker/assets/index.css",
    "react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css",
    "@trendmicro/react-toggle-switch/dist/react-toggle-switch.css",
  ],
  output: {
    path: DIST_DIR + "/app/",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/app/"
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
    '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5001',
        secure: false,
    },
}
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "eslint-loader",
        options: {
          failOnWarning: false,
          failOnError: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: SRC_DIR,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'stage-2']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: 'css-loader?importLoaders=1',
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader']),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: ['file-loader?context=src/images&name=images/[path][name].[ext]', {
          loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          query: {
            mozjpeg: {
              progressive: true,
            },
            gifsicle: {
              interlaced: false,
            },
            optipng: {
              optimizationLevel: 7,
            },
            pngquant: {
              quality: '75-90',
              speed: 3,
            },
          },
        }],
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        include: __dirname,
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        // loader: "url?limit=10000"
        use: "url-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "application.css",
      allChunks: true
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: FYI, Webpack `entry` points should only be JS files. SCSS files will be handled by loaders, which will pack the files into modules of strings in your JS bundle. If you remove the SCSS & CSS files from the `entry` array, it might resolve the babel error you're seeing.

Comment: Like @Atav32 said, only include your JS entry point, and I would do a relative path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

In order to compile your `scss`, webpack has to know about it. In order to let him know, you just import those `scss` files in your current component.

Now, what lasts you is to configure webpack. You are going to use [`sass-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader), `css-loader` and `style-loader`.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the most basic config that can be done.

If you want to have your compiled css into files, just use [`Mini-css-extract-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

```
module: {
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
    },
},
resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.css', '.scss'],
}
```